# Why isn't the TextView moving to the right?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Why isn't the text moving to the right?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBelow="true"
    android:text="happy birthday" />
```

Comment: Describe clearly, please. What layout are you using? And what do you want to for the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm, my guess is that the code you have given is part of a RelativeLayout. I suggest you give more context on the question, has it is quite incomplete and it is hard to answer an incomplete question. The TextView you have given should work, but we would need a clearer context (more of the code) to be able to know the issue.

A quick guess is that the parent object of the TextView (the RelativeLayout?) is not correct (width not set to match the full screen?). I test with only thins code and it seems to do what you want;

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBelow="true"
        android:text="happy birthday"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If your RelativeLayout is within another container, make sure that its size fits what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code, your TextView will be vertically centered, moved to the right.
It's better using layout_constraint. Your UI will be responsive.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="happy birthday" />
```